# Vue2 webpack production build spinning forever

Tags: webpack, vue.js, build, production

during one of our *bigger* commits for our Vue2 app the webpack production build process stopped working. I can identify the commit since when it happens but I'm wondering if there are any parameters I can provide to identify why it is hanging.

Basically the `building for production ...` is spinning forever without any notification of an error. The commit itself does not have any changes in the environment files.

Does webpack come with some extra parameters I can provide during:

`npm run build`

Thanks